Question about the Theorem 3.2 (a) and its proof in Serge Lang's Complex analysis
I am having some trouble understanding Theorem 3.2 (a) (and the prove of it) in Serge Lang s book, "Complex Analysis".
Theorem 3.2 (a) 
Let $f(T)=\sum a_nT^n$ be a non-constant power series, having non-zero radius of convergence. If $f(0)=0$, then there exists $s>0 $ s.t. $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ with $|z|\leq s$ and $z \neq 0$.
My thoughts on the statement of the Theorem:
The general statement seems to be that zero's of a power series (or the function that is determined by that power series) are "separated", i.e. zero's can't be arbitrary close to each other. Still I am a little bit confused why we do assume $f(origin)=0$. I guess the origin here is just a placeholder for some complex number.
I have a few questions regarding the formulation of this Theorem:
We assume that $\sum a_n T^n$ is a non-constant power series.
I do not know how this is meant exactly.
Does this mean, the constant term of the power series $a_0=0$?
Or that the sum converges to some value $f(z)$, which is dependent of $z$, i.e. non-constant. Or does it mean that the sequence $a_n$ is not a constant sequence i.e. $a_n=(a_0,a_0,a_0,...)$ ?
Here is the proof in the book:

We can write $f(z)=a_mz^m$ + higher terms and $a_m \neq 0$
$=a_mz^m(1+b_1z+b_2z^2+...)=a_mz_m(1+h(z))$, where
$h(z)=b_1z+b_2z^2+...$ is a power series having non-zero radios of
convergence and zero constant term.
For all sufficiently small $|z|$, the value $|h(z)|$  is small and
hence $1+h(z)\neq 0$. If $z\neq 0$, then $a_mz^m \neq 0$. This proves
the (first part) of the theorem.

Here are my thoghts on the proof (and some more detail):
By the definition $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$. Consider the sequence $a_n$ and let $m$ be the first coefficient that is $\neq 0$.
Thus we can write  $f(z)=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n z^n=a_mz^m+$ higher terms. Since $a_m \neq 0$, we can then write it as $a_m z^m (1+b_1z+b_2z^2+...)$, where $b_1=\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}$, $b_2=\frac{a_{m+2}}{a_m}$ and so on. We can then define $h(z):=b_1z+b_2z^2+....$ and write $a_mz^m (1+h(z))$.
Regarding $h(z)$:
Obviously $h(z)$ as a zero constant term. We need to verify that $h(z)$ has non-zero radius of convergence.
For that we know that $\sum a_n z^n$ has non-zero radius of convergence,call it $r$, and that $\frac{1}{r}=\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$. Now since $\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} \neq 0$, we can conclude that $\lim \sup |b_n|^{1/n}=\lim \sup |\frac{a_{n+m}}{a_m}|^{1/n} \neq 0$. Thus $h(z)$ has non-zero radius of convergence.
Here is where I am struggling:
How do I explicitly show that "For all sufficiently small $|z|$, the value $|h(z)|$ is small, and hence $1+h(z) \neq 0$."?
And the last part is a simple conclusion.
If $z \neq 0$, then $a_mz^m \neq 0$.
Afterthoughts:
In this prove there was no explicit $s > 0$ given such that the statement holds.I guess the value of $s$ has to to with the "all sufficiently small $|z|$" from the part where I am struggling.
But if not how could one determine some $s$ such that this holds?


"The power series $f(T)=∑a_nT^n$ is non-constant" means: $f$ is not a constant function (on the disc of convergence). Equivalently: $(a_0,a_1,a_n,\dots)\ne(a_0,0,0,0,\dots)$. (Note that we assume moreover that $a_0=f(0)=0$.)
Since $h$ is continuous at $0$ and $h(0)=0$, we have $\lim_{z\to0}h(z)=0$, i.e. "for all sufficiently small $|z|$, the value $|h(z)|$  is small".
The $s$ comes indeed from the previous point.

